# Project won't build after I changed the case in a citation key

Tags: biblatex

I've done extensive Internet searching to resolve this issue, with no luck. I changed the case of a citation key for consistency. The key is used throughout my thesis. The change was from Byrne_2020_apps to Byrne_2020_Apps.

I am now getting this error:

> Case mismatch error between cite keys Byrne_2020_apps and Byrne_2020_Apps.

It refers to an .aux file towards the end of my project. I have checked the corresponding .tex several times but can't find anywhere that uses the old lowercase spelling. I opened the .aux file and it uses the new uppercase spelling throughout. Overleaf, which I am using, seems to have correctly picked up on the new spelling, and suggests it when I begin to type a key. I have deleted all my cached files and rebuilt, a couple of times.

It is not an Overleaf-specific problem, because I pulled the project to my laptop and rebuilt from scratch with TexMaker, and that threw up the same issue.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, can‘t read your mind. Please extract the problem and post code. Thank you

Comment: have you regenerated the bibliography with biber (overleaf would do this for you)

Comment: @MS-SPO The only change I made was the case change to the citation key. This change is described in my question. A minimal project with a single citation key does not cause this issue when I change the case. I hesitate to post my entire thesis as it's quite long, though apparently not yet long enough.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for your question. I have rebuilt via Overleaf multiple times, including deleting the cache. I have also built separately on my laptop via Texmaker. Intermediate files are ignored when pulling the project to my laptop, so I think everything would be regenerated during the Texmaker build.

Comment: then you have mismatched key somewhere: seach or failing that, binary chop. start from a copy of your project and delete half fof it, if the problem remains, repeat. If the problem goes, undo that deletion and delete the other half. In the end you should end up with a 1-line document with a single `\cite` with the wrong value....

Comment: If you have downloaded the project then you can search for the cite key in all the files using the terminal/command line (`grep -R Byrne_2020_apps` in Linux and Mac and `findstr /s Byrne_2020_apps .\*` or something similar in Windows), then you will probably find the offending citation quickly.

Comment: Many thanks @David Carlisle. I found a reference that was still using the lowercase version. That was in the first chapter, but the error was generated for the .aux for chapter six. Not sure why the discrepancy but it's confusing! If you wanted to add your comment as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mismatched key somewhere: seach or failing that, binary chop. Start from a copy of your project and delete half fof it, if the problem remains, repeat. If the problem goes, undo that deletion and delete the other half. In the end you should end up with a 1-line document with a single `\cite` with the wrong value...

Comment: Thanks David. The faulty reference was near the beginning of the project, but the error message referenced a file that was near the end. I spent ages looking in the wrong place. This was confusing, something for others to watch out for!